# XAMPP mysql starting issues

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have two versions of XAMPP because I am running old code. One is version 5.6 while the other is version 7.3, my issue arises when I try to open mysql in version 5.6 it instead only turns on in version 7.3 and even when I try to stop it in version 7.3 it will still start again when I start it in version 5.6.

I have tried to flush privileges since on the terminal I was getting "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" but the error still persisted with the XAMPP's mysql.

Comment: There is no version 7.3 of MySQL available

Comment: These are XAMPP versions

Comment: At the XAMPP installation folder for respective versions,  Locate the my.ini configuration file for MySQL usually located in the xampp\mysql\bin directory. Look for the following line "port"; for one version  leave it for port=3306 and another change to port=3307

Comment: Have you installed portable versions of Xampp? If not, take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77143784/how-to-run-multiple-xampp-versions-on-windows/77398839#77398839

Answer (score 0):

Two databases instance on the same physical node must use different ports. for exmple：

mysql A：3306

mysql B：3307

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that two instances are running at the same time?