# How to run multiple xampp versions on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I need to run multiple php versions on windows, because I have different projects with php v7, v8 and v8.2. I am using XAMPP.So for that reason I've installed on my windows in C:\ directory XAMPP versions in files xamppv70,xamppv80 and xamppv82.
xamppv80 is running, no problem with it. But when i try to switch to other xampp versions i run on error.

```
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit
5:43:02 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 7.0.0
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
5:43:02 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xamppv70\"
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
5:43:02 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
5:43:02 PM  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
5:43:02 PM  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
5:43:02 PM  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
5:43:02 PM  [mysql]     Found Path: C:\xamppv80\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xamppv80\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
5:43:02 PM  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xamppv70\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xamppv70\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
5:43:02 PM  [main]  The FileZilla module is disabled
5:43:02 PM  [main]  The Mercury module is disabled
5:43:02 PM  [main]  The Tomcat module is disabled
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
5:43:02 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
```

So i noticed that it expects a different path. I tried configuring the default path location from
the Registry editor -> "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Apache2.4" changing the ImagePath there.

But even when i change the default path i still get the same error.

When closing Xampp that should close all running services. Also I checked the control panel and there is no running mysql or apache service there.

I expect when I close Xampp and change the default path to open different xampp with php version and to have no problem doing that.

What am I missing?

Btw i had no problems before. Idk what happened, but now i can't open xampp different versions except the v80.

Comment: It is like you are wasting your time. Sorry to say that. But my suggestion is to find more better server for your Windows that can switch different PHP versions easily.

Comment: I am now using laragon, on which I can switch to any PHP version easily.

Comment: From the log `MySQL Service detected with wrong path` is the only thing need of correcting. You should be looking specifically there to address the issues.

Comment: You should learn using Docker. Then you can use whatever you need for any application and this will work on any machine.

Comment: Do you install multiple versions of xampp? or do you change the php version **in** xampp? I think multiple versions of xampp is a better approach. saving in `C://xampp7.4`, `C://xampp8.1`, `C://xampp8.2` etc. Just make sure that you turn off all services of xampp before you open another instance of xampp with different version.

Comment: Just closing xampp is not enough IMO. You need to make sure you turn them off in the GUI. If you do close them without turning off the services, you can go to `services.msc` and turn them off there.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use different versions of Xampp in your computer, there are some basic rules you must follow:

- You can not use the default versions of the package: it is
  mandatory using the *portable versions*. If you already installed one or
  more non-portable Xampps, uninstall all of them.
- You can not add to the PATH variable the paths of Apache, PHP or MySQL
  executables, because you do not have a unique version of them. If you have
  added any path information to the PATH system variable, delete them
  all.

After cleaning all the messy you have inadvertently done, you can install the Xampps you want as follows:

1. Download the portable versions you want from [This page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/).
   Example: [Xampp 7.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.0.33/xampp-portable-win32-7.0.33-0-VC14.zip/download), [Xampp 8.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/8.0.25/xampp-portable-windows-x64-8.0.25-0-VS16.zip/download), [Xampp 8.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/8.2.4/xampp-portable-windows-x64-8.2.4-0-VS16.zip/download)
2. Unzip the files (one by one) in you C: or D: disk (in the root or inside another folder) and rename them according to the version of the package. Example: xampp70, xampp80, xampp82.
3. Open the first of these folders and double click the file
   **setup_xampp.bat**. Do the same with the other two folders.

That's all!